# Hibernate - Transferring a Collection of objects from one parent object to another

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 3 types of objects - Parent, Child, and ChildAttr

My goal is to transfer a subset of Children from one Parent to another using Hibernate (3.2.5).

Objects are structured as such:

```
public class Parent {
  Set<Child> children;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent")
  @Cascade( { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
  public Set<Child> getChildren() {
    return this.children;
  }

  public void setChildren(Set<Child> children) {
    this.children = children;
  }

}
```

...

```
public class Child {
  Set<ChildAttr> attributes;
  Parent parent;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "child")
  @Cascade( { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
  public Set<ChildAttr> getAttributes() {
    return this.attributes;
  }

  public void setAttributes(Set<ChildAttr> attributes) {
    this.attributes = attributes;
  }
}
```

...

```
public class ChildAttr {
  Child child;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", nullable = false)
  public Child getChild() {
    return this.child;
  }

  public void setChild(Child child) {
    this.child = child;
  }
}
```

Now say I run some client code that takes a subset of Parent A's Child objects and moves them to Parent B:

```
Set<Child> children = getChildrenToTransfer(transferCriteria, parentA);

parentA.getChildren().removeAll(children);
manager.saveOrUpdate(parentA); // method also calls flush();

parentB.getChildren().addAll(children);
manager.saveOrUpdate(parentB); // error thrown here.
```

I get an error thrown when trying to save parentB.

```
Found two representations of same collection: com.mycode.Child.attributes;
```

The application currently seems to do this work fine in multiple sessions - e.g. - some user comes along and removes the set of children, then some time later adds them to some other Parent. Moreover, I don't really understand why it's instantiating multiple versions of that attribute list when it should really just be one, even if the Parent changes.

What is causing the aforementioned error and how do I get around it?

Comment: Try to delete `@Cascade` annotations, you already passed cascades in `@OneToMany` after I deleted cascade annotations you example started to work, with cascades I get "detached entity passed to persist", not exactly your error but you may try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One rule of thumb: ensure the objects are consistent as an object graph before trying to persist them... iow you're removing all the children from parent A and are adding them to parentB but you have not updated the parent link for those children.

So I'd suggest the following:

add methods to Parent:

```
add(Child child) {
    child.setParent0(this);
    children.add(child);
}

remove(Child child) {
    child.setParent0(null);
    children.remove(child);
}
```

And then on Child:

```
setParent0(Parent parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}
setParent(Parent parent) {
     parent.add(this);
}
```

This way when you add from either direction you've got a consistent object model without the outside code knowing the details.

It makes more sense to remove from the parent...

So try with these methods.

Answer (score 1):

Seens thats because your bidirectional relation (parent-children). When you remove/add the child to one parent to another, you should update the `parent` reference.